# Sorting a set of lists in order of largest item in python

Tags: python, algorithm

someone know how to resolve this ?
I have this

```
[[1, 2, 3], [5, 4, 3], [2, 0, 1], [2, 3, 4, 1]]
```

and it's should return this

```
5 4 3
2 3 4 1
1 2 3
2 0 1
```

I'm trying this code

```
output = sorted(map(lambda a: a, list), reverse=True)
for i in output:                                       
   print(' '.join(str(e) for e in i))
```

but it's not return the good code

```
5 4 3
2 3 4 1
2 0 1
1 2 3
```

Comment: BTW This is a _list_ of lists, not a [set](https://realpython.com/python-sets/) of lists.

Answer (score 7):

Use `key` arg to set comparison criterion:

```
sorted(a, key=max, reverse=True)
```

Explained: `key` accepts a function. Elements will be passed to this function before comparison. Function returning maximum element happens to be a built-in, so we don't need to define it.

Also, it's worth mentioning why the first result, as list comparison semantics is useful sometimes. Python compares lists element by element, sort of like a string. The definitive factor is then the first element, if they're equal - second elements are compared, etc.

This is why the list starting with 5 comes first, than two lists starting with 2 are sorted by their second element, etc.